# Android PhoneGap to open a new Activity

Tags: android, cordova

I have an html page loaded with PhoneGap. The html is mine and is on the phone, so I have full control of it.

I would like to click on a link on the html page to open a new activity.

For Example:

index.html

```
...    
<a class="FullText" href="http://LinkToOpenPage" >Click me to open an activity</a>
...
```

MainActivity.java

```
...
public void OnReceiveLink(string Link)
{
if (Link=="LinkToOpenPage")
    {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), CalledActivity.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
    }
}
...
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Hey! Did you happen to figure this out? I'm looking for the same thing.

Comment: @Aneem Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at this plugin: http://smus.com/android-phonegap-plugins

> This how-to is about exposing additional Android functionality to the web with PhoneGap plugins. [Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) are a fundamental part of the Android ecosystem, allowing a sort of message-passing mechanism between applications, but they are not exposed to web applications. The sample Android plugin I wrote is called WebIntent, which lets you create a first class Android applications in JavaScript...
>
> This architecture is the key to unlock any Android functionality to your PhoneGap-wrapped mobile web application...

Answer (score 5):

Create a new class:

```
public class Variables {

    private WebView mAppView;
    private DroidGap mGap;

    public Variables(DroidGap gap, WebView view)
    {
        mAppView = view;
        mGap = gap;
    }

    public void changeActivity(){     
        Intent intent = new Intent(mGap, Example.class);
        mGap.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

in your main activity add:

```
super.init();
mc = new Variables(this, appView);
appView.addJavascriptInterface(mc, "MyCls");
```

in JavaScript call `window.MyCls` methods:

```
function changeActivity() {
    window.MyCls.changeActivity();
}
```