# Can we specify java activity path in html anchor tag to use java activity along with html?

Tags: android, cordova

I want to call a java activity on a press of link from html using anchor tag. So is that possible.. If not can anyone suggest me how we can call a java activity from html index page?

Comment: No we cann't specify link to activity but you can run a script under html and this script navigate you to your activity. I don't know absolute code of this but this works just serch a bit.

Comment: I tried searching on net and tried many codes from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395317/android-phonegap-to-open-a-new-activity/6396604#6396604 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11900544/how-to-call-android-activities-into-phonegap-html but then also i am unable to connect to my java activity using js.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to write a plugin. From you anchor tag you would call the [JavaScript interface](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide) of your plugin. Then through the cordova.exec method we use to communicate between JavaScript and Java your [Java Plugin method](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_plugin-development_android_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20Android) will be called.